# No horizontal scrolling in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

Are there any settings or options to enable horizontal scrolling for wide outputs (large pandas dataframes and even large plots) in Jupyter Lab? I can't seem to find anything and it's driving me crazy.

Also, this is on Windows 11 (Macbook seems to work fine), conda 23.5.2, jupyter lab 4.0.3 (conda-forge build pyhd8ed1ab_0).

Happy to provide any more information that may be helpful.

I've tried toggling on/off the 'enable/disable scrolling' option, which does nothing for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: There's an ongoing issue with this in certain browsers I gather from [this issue entitled 'Horizontal scrolling unavailable in Firefox'](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14625#issue-1736138036) and then noted specifically with version 4.0.3 [here entitled 'cell output cannot be scrolled horizontally in 4.0.3'](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14851). (That last issue was closed though as it is an ongoing issue for several versions now.) You don't specify your browsers, but seems likely same. Can you possible use a different browser while it is sorted?

Comment: Thanks for that @Wayne I'll add my setup to the issue post and make due in the meantime.

Comment: Let me preface by saying I don't know what I'm talking about. The horizontal scrollbar is properly shown in jupyter notebook 6.5.4 in conda base environment but not in 7.x. I assume this is a bug in 7.x. I blew away my dev environment and re-created. This also didn't work, guessing something to do with different PATH. I re-created dev environment again using conda create -n dev --clone base. Scrollbar is working because I'm back to using notebook 6.5.4. Conda has become the least stable part of my toolchain. Previously it was Nvidia GPU drivers but that seems solved.

Answer (score 6):

Found this workaround

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.jp-OutputArea-output {display:flex}</style>"))
```